# Не работает split("\n") при разбиении строки считанной из консоли

Tags: java, строки, консоль, split

Есть строка `1 1 1 1 1 1\n2 2 2 2 2 2\n3 3 3 3 3 3\n4 4 4 4 4 4`.
Если мы к ней применим `split("\n")` то получим массив строк разбитых по `\n`.
Однако если мы запросим пользователя ввести эту строку с консоли и также применим к этой строке `split("\n")`, то строка разбита не будет. Почему так?

Comment: А как вы считываете с консоли? Уверены, что строка там именно такая получается?

Comment: Уверен, проверял дебагером много раз. Читаю так Scanner sc=new Scanner(); String str=new String(sc.nextLine());

Comment: А вы в консоль так и вводите `\n`? Если да то вам `split('\\n')`. Консоль не предусматривает ввод возврата каретки (простым Read)

Comment: Да, просто в консоли печатаю эту строку или подобную. Или ее копирую и вставляю из буфера обмена. При этом split('\\n') не разбивает её. А вот так разбивает-> split(Pattern.quote("\\n")). Просто не пойму что не так делаю.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что пользователь не может вводить escape-последовательности прямым текстом. Это только в литералах вы можете написать `\n` или `%n` и они интерпретируются, как перенос строки.

Читайте ввод пользователя построчно (в цикле) в коллекцию, до тех пор, пока он не введет секретное слово (`quit`, например).

Ну или, если вы осознаете, что `\n` в вашем случае от пользователя **попадает в строку буквально**, как текст, то экранируйте обратный слэш: `split("\\n")`

Comment: Я так делал. При этом происходит та же самая история. Не разбивает. Разбивает есть написать вот так split(Pattern.quote("\\n")). Но если, честно, я не очень понимаю почему просто split("\\n") не работает.

Comment: @DmitriIGubenko Не разбивает пользовательский ввод или строку, заданную литералом? Либо одно, либо другое)

Comment: Литерал то разбивает=). А строку String полученную из пользовательского ввода нет. Пришлось к регулярным выражениям обращаться, хотя задача вроде как совсем элементарная и без них все должно и так работать)

Comment: @DmitriIGubenko split("\\n") разбивает литерал с "\n"? Вы уверены?)

Comment: String[] strArr="1 3 1 2\n2 3 2 2\n5 6 7 1\n3 3 1 0".split("\\n"); Вот, вот так работает.